# Can't retrieve HTML code generated by JavaScript (I use Java+Selenium)

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

I have run into a problem during I tried scrape data from website niche.com
I know that website is use JavaScript to render pages.

I have used Java and Selenium (tried FireFox and Chrome, both give the same results).

I tried download page https://www.niche.com/k12/search/best-schools/c/santa-clara-county-ca/
and save rendered page into text file on my laptop.

The code:

```
private WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
public final String load(String url) {
    String html = "";

    try {
        driver.navigate().to(url);
        html = gotHtml();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.warn(ex);
    }

    return html;
}

public String gotHtml() {
    try {
        return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.documentElement.outerHTML;").toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ex);
    }

    return driver.getPageSource();
}
```

On all other websites the code "return document.documentElement.outerHTML;" returned the rendered page, but for this one that code return not rendered page (page with javascript code, but without rendered html code).

This div must contains the rendered HTML code, but I got it empty:

```
<div class="platform__wrapper" id="app"><!-- react-empty: 1 --></div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, do not pay attention on the code:
    if (pageIsSuccessfullyDownloaded) {
        logger.info("Page successfully downloaded: " + url);
    } else {
        logger.error("Can't download page: " + url);
        logger.error("CSS selector must be on page: " + mustBeOnPage);
    }

I have forgotten to remove that.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't able to find that little grayish button "Edit".

Comment: I tried your URL in chrome using Python selenium and in both cases I am getting the correct code. May be some kind of Scraping protection when you hit too many times?